"Necessary cookies only" enables cookies it shouldn't
The current layout of the cookie setting currently allows selecting "necessary cookies only" with one click. However, selecting "necessary cookies only" still leaves "legitimate interests" cookies enabled, and I do not believe those cookies are necessary.
Instead, to deactivate "legitimate interests" cookies one has to click five separate buttons among two sub-menus:

Perfomance Cookies

Develop and improve services
Measure content performance
Measure advertising performance


Targeting Cookies

Understand audiences through statistics or combinations of data from different sources
Use limited data to select advertising



This answer from SE staff explains SE's reasons why:

The objection to legitimate interests selection does not apply to “Necessary cookies only” due to the ‘strictly necessary’ exemption. When the “Necessary cookies only” option is selected, it does not object to legitimate interest processing. An objection to legitimate interests requests clear affirmative action, as is dictated by TCF 2.2.

In short: SE argues that they can keep "legitimate interests" cookies enabled, unless someone explicitly objects to them.  That is because they are strictly needed and bound to the core functionality of this site; and they do not treat "necessary cookies only" as an explicit objection.
But this seems to me to be inaccurate. "Legitimate interests" cookies include cookies for measuring & selecting ads. Leaving those cookies enabled after a user clicks "necessary cookies only" seems to me to be in direct conflict to the GDPR in this context. While Recital 47 states:

[...]The processing of personal data for direct marketing purposes may be regarded as carried out for a legitimate interest.

which at first glance would appear to justify the use, it also states:

[...] At any rate the existence of a legitimate interest would need careful assessment including whether a data subject can reasonably expect at the time and in the context of the collection of the personal data that processing for that purpose may take place. The interests and fundamental rights of the data subject could in particular override the interest of the data controller where personal data are processed in circumstances where data subjects do not reasonably expect further processing.[...]

This reads to me (as consumer) that context is important. For example, if I look at a product on a web-store and I am to be shown related articles to the one I am looking at right now (and assuming there is no other reasonable technical way of doing this), I would reasonably expect the web store might have such "legitimate interests" and the site would not work properly without it.
I do not reasonably expect that any performance measurement, personal ad-selection or the like be done when it is not part of the core functionality of the website.
In this particular case, the core functionality of SO/SE is showing and letting me interact with questions and answers, so I do not expect that performance measurement and ad-selection would take place. Therefore, I do not believe those functions can reasonably be treated as "legitimate interests".
In other words: If a website works, even if I reject (or object) to the collection/usage of data for a given purpose, it can not really be considered strictly necessary.
Regardless of whether SE's current practice complies with the GDPR, the specific implementation of the cookie-settings-dialogue appears like a dark pattern.  The current system seems likely to mislead users into thinking that they have disabled ad-selection and performance measurement cookies by clicking "necessary cookies only", but SE keeps using them. I expect any reasonable person on the street would consider those cookies not "necessary", yet they remain enabled even after the user clicks "necessary cookies only". Moreover, SE makes it particularly hard to object to these cookies, requiring five clicks among two sub-menus.
I do not presume or imply maliciousness on the side of SE. I simply ask that "legitimate interests" cookies be disabled when a user clicks "necessary cookies only".  Alternatively, users should be given a way to object to "legitimate interests" cookies in a single click. That way, SE would be removing this apparent dark pattern, and better comply with the letter and spirit of the GDPR.
Here are some preliminary mock-up:
Alternative 1: Necessary cookies only should disable "legitimate interests" cookies:

Alternative 2: Add a new button named Object to all "legitimate interests"

After clicking the object-button to object, it could show Allow all "legitimate interests" to revert the decision.

The need for the "legitimate interests" cookies has also been questioned here. As of writing 2024-12-31, still no answer has been given.

Relevant history: https://www.cnil.fr/en/refusing-cookies-should-be-easy-accepting-them-cnil-continues-its-action-and-issues-new-orders CNILs guidance is that these 'dark patterns' are not just bad UX, they are a violation of the relevant directives, and CNIL has issued enforcement orders against companies for that.

@A-Tech, Thank you for the clarification.  I have revised the question to try to explain the background better (at least, I hope the explanation is better; I wrote what would have helped me to understand).  How does it look?
